# How to create a 3-segment donut/ring with CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm trying to split a ring up into 3 segments, each segment would have text on it centered. I can figure out the text part, but out of the ways I've tried to do the ring, I can't seem to get it to split into 3 equal parts.

Ideally, I'd like to do this with borders so I can add arrows to them, I tried to do this by splitting a circle but ran into problems with getting the text to sit where I need it. I'd like to keep this primarily to CSS, but I know the arrows on the segments will probably throw a roadblock.

This is what I am trying to do

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/wrqpas09/

```css
.segment {
  position: absolute;
  border: 20px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.s1 {
  border-top-color: green;
  left: 2px
}

.s2 {
  border-right-color: red;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px
}

.s3 {
  border-bottom-color: blue;
  top: 2px;
}

.s4 {
  border-left-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="segment s1"></div>
<div class="segment s2"></div>
<div class="segment s3"></div>
<div class="segment s4"></div>
```

Comment: Personally I'd probably go the SVG route for this one, but if you don't mind it being multiple elements it can be done in pure css too.

Comment: @ChrisW. SVG is my back pocket plan, but I know SVG gets a little wonky when you're trying to keep it responsive in ie11.

I'm open to multiple elements. I'd like it to essentially be broken up into segment elements with their content inside. This was just a quick code snippet to show how I want it to be built. (as opposed to the circle, with circle inside it route)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an idea with some complex background layer and without transparency:

I will first create the main shape without the arrow like below:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:50%;
  padding:50px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) content-box,
    linear-gradient(-35deg,green 59%, transparent 60%) bottom left/50% 50%,
    linear-gradient( 35deg,green 59%, transparent 60%) bottom right/50% 50%,
    linear-gradient(to right,red 50%,blue 0);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Then will add the first arrow on the top:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:50%;
  padding:50px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) content-box,
    linear-gradient(to top right, 
        red calc(50% - 6px),#fff calc(50% - 5px),
        #fff 50%,transparent 51%) calc(50% + 10px) -10px/20px 35px,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right, 
        red calc(50% - 6px),#fff calc(50% - 5px),
        #fff 50%,transparent 51%) calc(50% + 10px) 25px/20px 35px,
     
    
    linear-gradient(-35deg,green 59%, transparent 60%) bottom left/50% 50%,
    linear-gradient( 35deg,green 59%, transparent 60%) bottom right/50% 50%,
    linear-gradient(to right,red 50%,blue 0);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

We do the same for the other arrows but considering pseudo element that we rotate:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:50%;
  padding:50px;
  background:
     /*first arrow*/
    linear-gradient(to top right, 
        red calc(50% - 6px),#fff calc(50% - 5px),
        #fff 50%,transparent 51%) calc(50% + 10px) -10px/20px 35px,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right, 
        red calc(50% - 6px),#fff calc(50% - 5px),
        #fff 50%,transparent 51%) calc(50% + 10px) 25px/20px 35px,
    /*main background*/
    
    linear-gradient(-35deg,green 59%, transparent 60%) bottom left/50% 50%,
    linear-gradient( 35deg,green 59%, transparent 60%) bottom right/50% 50%,
    linear-gradient(to right,red 50%,blue 0);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position:relative;
}
.box::before,
.box::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  border-radius:50%;
  padding:50px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) content-box,
    linear-gradient(to top right, 
        var(--c) calc(50% - 6px),#fff calc(50% - 5px),
        #fff 50%,transparent 51%) calc(50% + 10px) -10px/20px 35px,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right, 
        var(--c) calc(50% - 6px),#fff calc(50% - 5px),
        #fff 50%,transparent 51%) calc(50% + 10px) 25px/20px 35px;
   background-repeat:no-repeat; 
}
.box::before {
  --c:green;
  transform:rotate(-125deg);
}
.box::after {
  --c:blue;
  transform:rotate(124deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

And with CSS variable it become more complex but easy to adjust:

```css
.box {
  /*coloration*/
  --c1:red;
  --c2:green;
  --c3:blue;
  --m:#fff; /*main background*/
  /**/
  --d:50px; /*the height of the borders*/
  --s:5px; /*the white distance*/


  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:50%;
  padding:var(--d);
  background:
     /*first arrow*/
    linear-gradient(to top right, 
        var(--c1) calc(50% - var(--s) - 1px),var(--m) calc(50% - var(--s)),
        var(--m) 50%,transparent 51%) calc(50% + 10px) calc(-2*var(--s))/20px calc(var(--d)/2 + 2*var(--s)),
    linear-gradient(to bottom right, 
        var(--c1) calc(50% - var(--s) - 1px),var(--m) calc(50% - var(--s)),
        var(--m) 50%,transparent 51%) calc(50% + 10px) calc(var(--d)/2)/20px calc(var(--d)/2 + 2*var(--s)),
    /*main background*/
    
    linear-gradient(-35deg,var(--c2) 59%, transparent 60%) bottom left/50% 50%,
    linear-gradient( 35deg,var(--c2) 59%, transparent 60%) bottom right/50% 50%,
    linear-gradient(to right,var(--c1) 50%,var(--c3) 0),
    var(--m);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
}
.box::before,
.box::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  border-radius:50%;
  padding:var(--d);
  background:
    linear-gradient(var(--m),var(--m)) content-box,
    linear-gradient(to top right, 
        var(--c) calc(50% - var(--s) - 1px),var(--m) calc(50% - var(--s)),
        var(--m) 50%,transparent 51%) calc(50% + 10px) calc(-2*var(--s))/20px calc(var(--d)/2 + 2*var(--s)),
    linear-gradient(to bottom right, 
        var(--c) calc(50% - var(--s) - 1px),var(--m) calc(50% - var(--s)),
        var(--m) 50%,transparent 51%) calc(50% + 10px) calc(var(--d)/2)/20px calc(var(--d)/2 + 2*var(--s));
   background-repeat:no-repeat; 
}
.box::before {
  --c:var(--c2);
  transform:rotate(-125deg);
}
.box::after {
  --c:var(--c3);
  transform:rotate(124deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
<div class="box" style="--c1:orange;--c3:purple;--d:60px;--s:2px">
</div>

<div class="box" style="--c2:black;--d:20px;--s:10px;--m:grey">
</div>
```

Comment: Oh this is perfect, I forgot all about doing it as a linear gradient, thanks for the help!